# wget not downloading from authentic https url vaultpress

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu, curl, wget

I'm using VaultPress to take my WordPress blog's backup
https://dashboard.vaultpress.com/

After clicking the download backup button, this site sends me a link from where I can download. When I click on this link, it starts downloading my backup in the browser, and that's perfect. But I'm trying to download this in my Ubuntu system using `wget` or `curl` but no success till now. Here is what the download URL looks like:
https://dashboard.vaultpress.com/12345/restore/?step=4&job=12345678&check=.

```
eric@eric:~# wget https://dashboard.vaultpress.com/12345/restore/?step=4&job=12345678&check=<somehashedvalue>
[5] 2229
[6] 2230
[6]   Done                    job=12345678
eric@eric:~# --2015-02-08 02:25:07--  https://dashboard.vaultpress.com/12345/restore/?step=4
Resolving dashboard.vaultpress.com (dashboard.vaultpress.com)... 192.0.96.249, 192.0.96.250
Connecting to dashboard.vaultpress.com (dashboard.vaultpress.com)|192.0.96.249|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: / [following]
--2015-02-08 02:25:09--  https://dashboard.vaultpress.com/
Reusing existing connection to dashboard.vaultpress.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /account/login/ [following]
--2015-02-08 02:25:09--  https://dashboard.vaultpress.com/account/login/
Reusing existing connection to dashboard.vaultpress.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html?step=4’

    [ <=>                                                                                                   ] 7,709       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-02-08 02:25:09 (20.9 MB/s) - ‘index.html?step=4’ saved [7709]
```

PS: The file size is almost 1 GB.

Then I used user/pass:

`eric@eric:~# wget --user <myusername> --password <mypassword> https://aboveurl`

I even used `--ask-password`:

`eric@eric:~# wget --user <myusername> --ask-password https://aboveurl`

But in this case, instead of asking password it completes the action and then asks for the password in another shell (I don't know the exact term), something like this:

```
eric@eric:~# wget --user <myusername> --ask-password https://dashboard.vaultpress.com/12345/restore/?step=4&job=12345678&check=<hashedvalue>
[1] 1979
[2] 1980
eric@eric:~# Password for user ‘<myusername>’: <mypassword-here>
<mypassword>: command not found
```

And then finally, I gave a try to `curl`:

```
eric@eric:~# curl -u <myusername>:<mypassword> https://dashboard.vaultpress.com/12345/restore/?step=4&job=12345678&check=<hashedvalue>
[5] 2010
[6] 2011
eric@eric:~#
```

I don't know what's happening? What are those `[5] 2010 [6] 2011 or [5] 2229`

This solution is also not working:
[wget with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampersands in your URL make Linux create new processes running in the background. The PID is printed out behind the number in the square brackets.

Write the URL within double quotes and try again:

```
wget "https://dashboard.vaultpress.com/12345/restore/?step=4&job=12345678&check=<somehashedvalue>"
```